# How to apply css style in codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I am having trouble with applying CSS style in my view.

I have set base_url in config.php also..

```html
config['base_url']='http://localhost/test_project/'
```

My code is

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?> css/mycss.css" >
</link>

</head>

<body>

<p> This is test.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS code is

```css
p
{
 color:#0066CC;
}
```

But it shows only simple text..
How to apply CSS in codeigniter....

Answer (score 0):

Put the path inside the function. Include `rel="stylesheet"` in the link tag. You don't need the closing `</link>` either.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('css/mycss.css'); ?>">
```

View the source of the page, you should see the CSS included like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/test_project/css/mycss.css">
```

Comment: still not working... source code of page display link but can't apply it.

Comment: What does the source show? Paste the source for the entire page, since it's a small test page.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link type="text/css" href="http://localhost/fleetmaster/css/mycss.css" >
</link>

</head>

<body>
<p> This is test</p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: So it's not using http://localhost/test_project/ ... are you sure you have `/application/config/config.php` set with `$config['base_url']='http://localhost/test_project/';`?

Comment: Does Chrome Developer Tools Network tab show a 404 error on the file? Did you name it the same?

Comment: i got the output "This is test." but not with color. It shows in BLACK color text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63176/discussion-between-slapyo-and-mehul).

Answer (score 0):

You need put in html tag link the attribute **rel="stylesheet"**

```
<link type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('css/mycss.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Check with your firebug if your css files is load fine.

You could use html tag called "base" for example:

```
<base href="http://url" />
```

In your code:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
   <base href="<?php echo base_url()?>" />
   <link type="text/css" href="css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
</head>
<body>
   <p> This is test.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the default function of codeigniter. For example:

```
echo link_tag('assets/css/bootstrap.css');
```